# How can I use different symbols for groups of x*y=z plots in proc gplot?

Tags: graph, sas, symbols

**What I'm trying to do:**

I'm creating plots using the code below. PERIOD has 3 different values, so the plot and plot2 statements each create 3 series on the plot via an x*y=z type of plot request. I want the 3 series from the plot statement to have symbols that are joined up, and I want the 3 series from the plot2 statement to have symbols that are not joined up. Whatever solution I come up with needs to work inside a macro.

**The problem**

No matter what I try, all 6 series on each chart end up using the same symbols. All the other plot options I'm defining outside the proc gplot calls are being picked up correctly, so what am I doing wrong with the symbol definitions? I would be grateful if someone could post an example of the correct syntax.

**References**

I found this link, which produces a very similar sort of plot with different symbols for the plot and plot2 series, but it doesn't use an x*y=z plot request:

http://support.sas.com/techsup/technote/ts422.html

I also found this link, which contains some code that uses an x*y = z request but without a plot2 statement:

http://www.sfu.ca/sasdoc/sashtml/ets/chap2/sect27.htm

This page claims it's possible to do both at the same time and get different symbols for each series using symbols statments, but doesn't actually provide the necessary code to do it:

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/graphref/63022/HTML/default/gplot-plot2.htm#gplot-fig5

**Code examples**

If I run this code, all 6 series are plotted with interpol = none:

```
%macro sr_elas_plots(VAR);
  goptions reset = all;
  axis1 label=(angle = 90);
  legend1 label=('Obs. elasticity');
  legend2 label=('Quote volume');

  proc gplot data = _p_&VAR;
  symbol1 interpol=join value=dot height=3;
  symbol2 interpol=join value=dot height=3;
  symbol3 interpol=join value=dot height=3;

    plot  Elasticity*&VAR = PERIOD / legend = legend1 vaxis=axis1;
  symbol1 interpol=none value = dot height=3;
  symbol2 interpol=none value = dot height=3;
  symbol3 interpol=none value = dot height=3;

    plot2 QUOTES*&VAR = PERIOD / legend = legend2; 
    by    NBIND CHANNEL;
  run;
  quit;
%mend sr_elas_plots;
```

If I run this code, however, all 6 are plotted with interpol = join:

```
%macro sr_elas_plots(VAR);
  goptions reset = all;
  axis1 label=(angle = 90);
  legend1 label=('Obs. elasticity');
  legend2 label=('Quote volume');

  proc gplot data = _p_&VAR;
  symbol1 interpol=join value=dot height=3;
  symbol2 interpol=join value=dot height=3;
  symbol3 interpol=join value=dot height=3;

    plot  Elasticity*&VAR = PERIOD / legend = legend1 vaxis=axis1;
  symbol4 interpol=none value = dot height=3;
  symbol5 interpol=none value = dot height=3;
  symbol6 interpol=none value = dot height=3;

    plot2 QUOTES*&VAR = PERIOD / legend = legend2; 
    by    NBIND CHANNEL;
  run;
  quit;
%mend sr_elas_plots;
```

**Other things I've tried**

- If I move the 6 different symbol statements so they're all before the first plot statement, all 6 series are plotted with interpol = join.
- If I move the 6 different symbol statements outside the proc gplot but still inside the macro, all 6 series are plotted with interpol = join.
- If I move the 6 different symbol statements outside the macro, and remove the goptions reset=all from the macro, all 6 series are plotted with interpol = join.
- If I assign 6 different value= options in the 6 different symbol statements (to try to force them to plot different symbols), the value from symbol4 is used for all 6 series.
- If I use 2 variables with 6 different values for z in my 2 x*y = z requests, the same thing still happens.

How can I get 3 series of each type when I have an x*y=z plot request in both the plot **and** plot2 statements?

Comment: Note that the symbol statements are global statements. For me they belong outside the step. I've not used GRAPH in a while so cannot give a definitive answer. Perhaps you only need two SYMBOL statements. I'm thinking that in both cases you give, the SYMBOL1 and SYMBOL2 statements are used.

Comment: @DavB When I set up 6 symbol statements, the SYMBOL1-3 statements are apparently ignored and the settings for SYMBOL4 are applied to every series (as per the other things I've tried). Setting only 2 symbol statements also doesn't work.

Annoyingly, there doesn't seem to be any explicit way of matching up a plot series to a symbol statement.

Comment: @user667489... you could take a look at http://support.sas.com/kb/25/581.html. It might guide you in the right direction. If I get a chance later, I'll take a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed! From deep within the documentation for the symbol statement:

> **Controlling Consecutive SYMBOL Statements**
>
> If you specify consecutively numbered SYMBOL statements and you want
>   SAS/GRAPH to use each definition only once, use color specifications
>   to ensure each SYMBOL statement generates only one symbol definition.

All I had to do was add a color= option to each of the 6 symbol statements, and then each one was used exactly once in the order I expected. This is certainly one of the less intuitive aspects of SAS that I've come across, to put it mildly.

Comment: If you don't specify the color then it uses the first symbol statement cycling through the colors until it runs out. Then if needed it will move onto the second or third symbol statement.