# SAS: How SAS handles color assignment when color not specified in SYMBOL statement

Tags: colors, sas, logic, symbols

**Question:** What line of reasoning leads SAS to plot the MaxHR using squares despite triangles having been specified in the SYMBOL2 statement?

Using SAS 9.4:

```
symbol1 interpol=spline value=square;
symbol2 interpol=spline value=triangle;
proc gplot data=sasuser.stresstest;
   plot  RestHR*Date 
         MaxHR*date
           /overlay;
run;
quit;
```

[image: Sample Plot Using Built-in Data Set]

---

**Enter Gumshoe Mode**

**tl;dr:** How do SYMBOL statements operate?

The only explanation I have been able to find is that the SAS/GRAPH software cycles each SYMBOL statement through the current list of colors before moving on to the next SYMBOL statement.  Since the first two colors in the the list are blue and red, the SYMBOL2 statement isn't needed and so isn't used.

The documentation for ["How SYMBOL Definitions are Generated"](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/graphref/67881/HTML/default/n0c0j84n1e2jz9n1bhkn41o3v0d6.htm#n0xm4mezu8ayarn1j84yiwhuc7es/) echoes much of this, as well as the ["Controlling Consecutive SYMBOL Statements"](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/graphref/67881/HTML/default/n0c0j84n1e2jz9n1bhkn41o3v0d6.htm#n1owqpymxyvdxin1udw01foi3kw2).

It appears that the behavior of SYMBOL statements is controlled primarily by color designations.  There exists a mysterious default color list directing the compilers actions and it is only when that list has been exhausted that, in the absence of explicit color declarations within each SYMBOL statement, a subsequent SYMBOL statement will be processed.

As global options, SYMBOL statements seem like they should operate similar to `ODS listing` or `LIBNAME` declarations in that

1) the documentation literally calls them

> TYPE: Global

and

2) the documentation states

> SYMBOL definitions can be defined anywhere in your SAS program. They are global and remain in effect until canceled or until you end your SAS session.

By the [Global Statements by Category](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lestmtsref/68024/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0r3hrjzyehvt4n1snm4pikh7ayy.htm) documentation, SYMBOL statements appear to fall within the "Data Access" category.  Yet, as evidenced by the example I have provided, they don't behave that way.  Each subsequent `ODS output` or `LIBNAME` statement is evaluated whereas each subsequent SYMBOL statement may or may not be.

So, how do SYMBOL statements operate?

Comment: I can't answer your question but I would very highly recommend looking into GTL/SG procedures instead of SAS/Graph. If only for better quality graphs. Also, attribute maps make it much easier to specify symbols and colours.

Comment: The example in the doc has the same issue. Should be an filled and outline circle but that doesn't appear to be the case. http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/graphref/67881/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p08eh1sr05yby4n1grpec8wzw0p4.htm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use different symbols for groups of x\*y=z plots in proc gplot?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521169/how-can-i-use-different-symbols-for-groups-of-xy-z-plots-in-proc-gplot)

Comment: If you don't set the color then it will "generate" symbols for each of the colors in your color list setting. http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/graphref/67881/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0c0j84n1e2jz9n1bhkn41o3v0d6.htm

Answer (score 0):

Ugh - after a bit of testing it seems that unless you specify the color option on the symbol statement it just ignores symbol statements (other than the first).

**Code showing problem:**

```
goptions reset=all border;

symbol1 interpol=spline value=triangle;
symbol2 interpol=spline value=circle  ;
symbol3 interpol=spline value=square  ;

proc gplot data=sashelp.stocks;
   plot open*date=stock / hminor=0;;             
run;
quit;
```

**Fix:**

Simply add the color to the end of the symbol statements:

```
symbol1 interpol=spline value=triangle c=steelblue;
symbol2 interpol=spline value=circle   c=indigo   ;
symbol3 interpol=spline value=square   c=orchid   ;
```

**Original Image:**

[image]

**Fixed Image:**

[image]

**EDIT:** I definitely agree with Reeza - start switching to `proc sgrender` which has much better documentation and support and produces better looking charts.  Not only that but `proc gplot` is now basically a legacy proc.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation of `proc sgrender`!  All the resources I have come across use `gplot`.  It's good to know there are other options.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. If you do not specify a COLOR on the SYMBOL statement then SAS/GRAPH will repeat the SYMBOL statement until it has used up the list of colors you have set.

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/graphref/67881/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0c0j84n1e2jz9n1bhkn41o3v0d6.htm

> Each time a default definition is required, SAS/GRAPH takes the first
>   default plot symbol or line type and uses it with the first color in
>   the color list. If more than one definition is required, it uses the
>   same plot symbol or line type with the next color in the color list.
>   It continues until all the colors have been used once. If more
>   definitions are needed, SAS/GRAPH selects the second default plot
>   symbol or line type and rotates it through the color list. It
>   continues in this fashion, selecting default plot symbols or line
>   types and cycling them through the color list until all the required
>   definitions are generated.

You can prevent this by setting a COLOR on the SYMBOL statement. Or

> A color can be specified with the CSYMBOL= option in the GOPTIONS
>   statement. In this case, each default plot symbol or line type is used
>   once with the specified color, and the colors in the color list are
>   ignored